# React intinite scroll and scrollTo

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I wanted to use infinite scroll to improve performance of my page. But I have also functionality of toolbar, which scrollsTo selected item(and of course if selected item would not be attached to DOM it would not work). Has anyone had similar problem and figured out how this can be approached?